# getdata on File input to return only filename, not array of details

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form2, zend-file

I have a form that has a fieldset with a file upload field in it. When I do a `var_dump` on `$form->getData()` I am being shown an array of data for the file field:

```
array (size=13)
  'logo' => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => string 'my-image.gif' (length=12)
      'type' => string 'image/gif' (length=9)
      'tmp_name' => string 'C:\xampp\htdocs\images\my-image.gif' (length=35)
      'error' => int 0
      'size' => int 391
  //... other fields here
```

How do get the element to return only the name when I call `getData`?

e.g.

```
array (size=13)
  'logo' => string 'my-image.gif' (length=12)
  //... other fields here
```

I am using the form for other things and have already overridden `getData` so would like to keep the answer located in the fieldset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the getData() method in your form.

```
public function getData()
{
    $data = parent::getData();
    $logo = $data['logo'];
    $data['logo'] = $logo['name'];
    return $data;
}
```

Add all necessary precautions to ensure the existence of the keys in the arrays.

**Supplements for a fieldset**

Using a fileset, you can use a Filter to change the return file structure :

```
namespace your\namespace;

use Zend\Filter;

class FilterFileName extends Filter\AbstractFilter
{
public function filter($value)
{
        if (! is_scalar($value) && ! is_array($value)) {
            return $value;
        }
        if (is_array($value)) {
            if (! isset($value['name'])) {
                return $value;
            }
            $return = $value['name'];
        } else {
            $return = $value;
        }
        return $return;
    }
}
```

Your fieldset class must implement InputFilterProviderInterface

```
use your\namespace\FilterFileName;

class YourFieldset extends ZendFiedset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // your code ... like :
        parent::__construct('logo');

        $file_element = new Element\File('my-element-file');
        $file_element->setLabel('Chooze')
            ->setAttribute('id', 'my-element-file')
            ->setOption('error_attributes', [
               'class' => 'form-error'
        ]);
        $this->add($file_element);            
    }
    public function getInputFilterSpecification()
    {
        return [
            'element-file' => [
                'name' => 'my-element-file',
                'filters' => [
                    ['name' => FilterFileName::class]
                ]
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

You can chain multiple filters, eg to rename the file before.

Comment: I have already overridden `getData` in the form for something else. Is there a way to do this in the fieldset object?

Comment: I just completed my answer for a fieldset.